# Understanding しょう in いいことしょう

Tags: verbs

How is しょう being used in this expression? Is he saying "Let's have a good time" or something more nuanced? Context is that it's a creepy dude saying it to a girl as she approaches.

Comment: しょう looks like the volitional form of する, but that would be しよう.

Answer (score 2):

Practically it is a way to say *let's go to bed together*. Literally it means *let's do a good thing* and the good thing is a euphemism for sexual act (*good* being interpreted as pleasure).

Comment: thank you so much!